# Add class only to parent li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this structure:

```
<li id="artworks"><a href="#">ARTWORK</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <img src="../img/submenu.png" alt="submenu" width="62" height="1" />
                    <li id="sweetlife"><a href="#">Sweet Life</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pleasure</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bienal de la habana</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Estudios de craneos</a></li>width="62" height="1" />
                </ul>
            </li>
```

And i'm using this script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#artworks li').addClass('active')
      });
    </script>
```

The problem is that I want to add the active class only to the "li id="artworks"" element but, with the script it adds to all the "li" that belongs to the #artworks.

How can I point just to the parent li?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#artworks > a').addClass('active')
```

Comment: why is that "perfectly"? you ask for the parent li, this code select the a in the li.

Answer (score 2):

The code should be

```
$('#artworks').addClass('active')​;
```

You can see the working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2vaQB/)

Answer (score 1):

Change this code:

```
$('#artworks li').addClass('active')
```

to this:

```
$('#artworks').addClass('active')
```

Why does this work?
`#artworks` identifies any element with an ID of 'artworks' (hopefully just one!)  Following that with a space and an element tells jQuery to match all elements of that type that are children of `#artwork`.  To read up on the selector syntax: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want I think:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('li#artworks').addClass('active')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
$('#artworks').addClass('active')​;
```